# How to create correct toggle in Angular controller with eventListener for body?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add event listener on click for body in controller. For that I added function that should inverse variable **is_shown** . The problem is variable **is_shown** is not become inversed.

Is it possible to inverse variable **is_shown** only in controller without adding directive like "ng-click"?

*Angular version - 1.6.2*

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>{{is_shown}}</p>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.is_shown = false;

    $scope.toggleCont = function(){
        alert('fired');
        $scope.is_shown = !$scope.is_shown;
    };

    var body = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));

    body.on("click", function (e) {
        $scope.toggleCont();
    });
```

*In chrome debugger mode variable is_shown become inversed, but in p changes is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$scope.$apply();` after calling the toggle function. body.on() is not an angular event so you need this to update the values. But this is not the best way to achieve what you want.
You can create a directive, attach it to body element and do the job there like this (inside link function):

```
element.on("click", (e: JQueryEventObject) => {

});
```